# KnockoutJS: Making sure items are removing before adding new ones

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm running into an issue where ever so often my data isn't being updated properly in my model. I've create a fiddle for it here: https://jsfiddle.net/wzhv5ghy/

In the code all the updates to the model are handled by this function:

```
self.updateData = function (data) {         
    self.deliveryItems.removeAll(); // Sometimes our data won't replace correctly so lets kill everything here and then add it from scratch         

    if ( data != null )
        self.deliveryItems(data);               

    self.showLoadingNotice(false);

    // let the sorting plugin know that we made a update
    $("#deliveryItemsTable").trigger("update");

    //self.showTable(true);
    //console.log(data);

    // We moved this to functions.js since we use it multiple times
    //setupDeliveryItemsTable();        
};
```

I put it in a single function to make it easier when updating the code using various JSON calls.

The issue thats happening is that every so often the page will show old data (say 1000 lines) in the table while the following code will display 1 as the count of the models data:

```
<span data-bind="text: deliveryItems().length"></span>
```

My guess is that this line:
    self.deliveryItems.removeAll();

is not running before this line 
    self.deliveryItems(data);

How can I make sure that all items are removed from the model and table before the model is updated with the fresh data?

Comment: Did you try to self.deliveryItems([]) instead of self.deliveryItems.removeAll();?

Comment: Your fiddle lacks any HTML.

Comment: I guess it's because of your sorting plugin. Looks like both the plugin and KO are trying to maintain own item order and this causes unpredictable results. You should consider either to implement sorting purely with KO or to bind plain (unobservable) array of items.

Comment: @f_martinez I think you hit the nail on the head. I didn't think about this.

Comment: We prefer to avoid [solved] title edits here. Would you add an answer below, summarising the solution from the comments?

Comment: Answer has been added, thanks for correcting me on that.

Answer (score 0):

Like @f_martinez pointed out our issue was with the jQuery Tablesorter plugin and KO fighting to update the same table. To get around this I ended up using the code below to switch to a KO tablesorting function. The sorting seems to be slower than the Tablesorter version but it's better than having bad data.

```
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
// Knockout.js Functions
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
ko.bindingHandlers.sort = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var asc = false;
        element.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        //console.log(element);

        element.onclick = function(){
            var value = valueAccessor();
            var prop = value.prop;
            var data = value.arr;

            asc = !asc;

            data.sort(function(left, right){
                var rec1 = left;
                var rec2 = right;

                if(!asc) {
                    rec1 = right;
                    rec2 = left;
                }

                var props = prop.split('.');
                for(var i in props){
                    var propName = props[i];
                    var parenIndex = propName.indexOf('()');
                    if(parenIndex > 0){
                        propName = propName.substring(0, parenIndex);
                        rec1 = rec1[propName]();
                        rec2 = rec2[propName]();
                    } else {
                        rec1 = rec1[propName];
                        rec2 = rec2[propName];
                    }
                }

                return rec1 == rec2 ? 0 : rec1 < rec2 ? -1 : 1;
            });
        };
    }
};
```

Here's the code for the table itself:

```
    <div class="alert alert-info" data-bind="visible: showLoadingNotice">
        Loading...
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="deliveryItemsTable" data-bind="visible: showTable">
        <thead> 
            <tr class="title1">
                <td colspan="100%">Delivery Items ( <span data-bind="text: deliveryItems().length"></span> )</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="title2">
                <th class="header" data-bind="sort: { arr: deliveryItems, prop: 'created_on' }">Created On</th>
                <th class="header" data-bind="sort: { arr: deliveryItems, prop: 'company_name' }">Company</th>
                <th class="header" data-bind="sort: { arr: deliveryItems, prop: 'product_number_company' }">Item Number</th>
                <th class="header" data-bind="sort: { arr: deliveryItems, prop: 'client_phone_number' }">Phone Number</th>
                <th data-bind="sort: { arr: deliveryItems, prop: 'price_to_display' }">Price</th>
                <th class="header" data-bind="sort: { arr: deliveryItems, prop: 'location' }">Location</th>
                <th class="header" data-bind="sort: { arr: deliveryItems, prop: 'notes' }">Notes</th>
                <th class="header" data-bind="sort: { arr: deliveryItems, prop: 'delivered_by_text' }">Delivery Driver</th>
                <th class="header" data-bind="sort: { arr: deliveryItems, prop: 'status_labels' }">Status</th>
                <th class="header nowrap"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: deliveryItems">
            <tr data-bind="attr: {id: 'row_' + id }">
                <td data-bind="text: created_on"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: company_name"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: product_number_company"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: client_phone_number"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: formatCurrency(price_to_display)"></td>
                <td>
                    <span data-bind="text: location, attr: {id: 'edit-delivery_items-' + id + '_location' }"></span>
                    <button data-bind="click: $root.editLocation, visible: $root.canEdit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" title="Edit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span data-bind="text: notes, attr: {id: 'edit-delivery_items-' + id + '_notes' }"></span>
                    <button data-bind="click: $root.editNotes, visible: $root.canEdit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" title="Edit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span data-bind="text: delivered_by_text, attr: {id: 'edit_select-delivery_items-' + id + '_delivered_by' }"></span>
                    <button data-bind="click: $root.editDeliveryDriver, visible: $root.canEdit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" title="Edit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></button>
                </td>                   
                <td data-bind="html: status_labels"></td>
                <td class="center"><span class="btn-group">
                    <button data-bind="click: $root.markAsDelivered, visible: $root.canMarkComplete" class="btn btn-default" title="Mark as delivered"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i></button>
                    <a data-bind="attr: {href: 'index.php?action=editDeliveryItem&amp;id=' + id }, visible: $root.canEdit" class="btn btn-default" title="Edit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a> 
                </span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="alert alert-info" data-bind="visible: showLoadingNotice">
        Loading...
    </div>
    <div id="deliveryItemsTableUpdateNotice"></div>
```